# Blender collision sensor is triggered twice

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have this script with the module `collision` which is called when the player collides with any of two cylinders in the scene, the module increments the counter in a text object that in a separate scene that overlays the main scene

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

dynamicText = scene.objects['Text']

def collision():
    dynamicText.text = str(int(dynamicText.text)+1)
```

This the logic behind the cylinders that triggers the collision and send the message to the text object to increment the counter.

[image]

This is the login in the the text object

[image]

The problem is that the counter is incremented twice per collision, and I don’t see an obvious way to filter the second time the module is called.

This is the [blend file](https://anonfiles.com/file/90b0de300887b8668ef5e0d145db01c6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, collision sensors fire twice by design.  Once when set True, and another when False.

This isn't a problem when connected to an And or Not controller (because they check) but in a script you'll have to do something like this:

```
def collision(cont):
    # Loops through all connected sensors and returns if one is False
    # Basically makes it work like an And conroller.
    for sens in cont.sensors:
        if not sens.positive:
            return
    ...
```

Comment: Also [this](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bge.logic.html) helped me to figure out a way to test only the sensor that receives the message sent by the colliding cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why message pulses twice but

I changed the logic on Text to message> property "collideCount" add 1

Then added an always sensor true level triggering at frequency 3 
connected to script

```
import bge    
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

dynamicText = scene.objects['Text']

def main():
    dynamicText.text = str(dynamicText["collideCount"])
main()
```

[new logic http://ball2000.net/blender/images/messageBounce.png](http://ball2000.net/blender/images/messageBounce.png)

Comment: I see what you mean, the first time `message` is triggered it adds 1 to `collideCount`, the second time it copies the value to `text`, also adding 0.5 each time `message`is called could work too.

Comment: A good a theory as any; I honestly don't know why it works!  : )

Comment: Prof Monster doesn't say anything about messages pulsing twice; and I couldn't get the double-count thing to happen by modifying the 'homework...' or 'ending' the message-sending object..  Just something weird about your blend I think...  
  
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249078